# Is there a language where we can mark value as result and then continue function/method body?

Tags: return, return-value

I was reading smalltalk tutorial and this idea came to my mind.

Assume we have some language and there instead of return we're marking some value as final return value and then we continue method, once method end is reached - no matter what else was called we're returning marked value unless something else specified manually like this:
Let's say ^^ is a operator that marks value for return if no explicit return is found till end of method

```
m1()
{
 ^^1;
 some_other_code;
}

m2(par)
{
 ^^2;
 if par == 1: return 1;
 some code;
}

m3(par)
{
 if par == 1: return 1;
 else if par == 0: ^^0;
 do some stuff;
 if par < 0: return -1;
}

m1() should return 1
m2(0) should return 2
m2(1) should return 1
m3(0) should return 0
m3(1) should return 1
m3(-2) should return -1
```

This is a little similar to ruby's tap() but not the same

Comment: I honestly don't know whether this could be on-topic for [SO], or not (as such I'm not voting in any way (whether up, down or 'to-close')); but the nature of the question asked leads me to suggest that [programmers.se] *might* be a better fit.

Comment: @DavidThomas We usually close "list of languages" questions like this on Programmers.

Comment: @Ixrec: so, perhaps [softwarerecs.se]?

Answer (score 1):

Pascal did that. The return value was set by assigning to the function name. Swift does something not quite the same: You can mark code anywhere that will be executed when the function exits. Your return statement exists, but only after other code written somewhere else gets performed.

Comment: VB6/VBA does that also (set the return value by assigning to the function name).

Comment: Visual Basic also does that. You could assign a value to the function name and it would be returned when the end of the function was reached or an 'Exit Function' statement was reached. However, if it reached an explicit 'Return _value_' statement, it would return that _value_ instead.